# Executing prepared call 1031: ORA-0131

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have made a JNDI connection to a database on which I try to execute a function with java.sql.Connection.prepareCall method.

However when I try to execute the function, on an Oracle database, I get the error: "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges tips"

When I run the function native, directly on database on the same schema as used for JNDI connection, the function runs without any issue.

Can you please give some advice on how I should manage to run the function on database.

Sincerely,

Comment: Are you connecting with same user as "natively" , right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using same schema for JNDI as connecting directly to database.

Comment: When you connect natively, do you use "as sysdba" option??

Comment: No I don't connect as sysdba :-( . I simply call the function (schema name. function name) from an anonymous block in which I declare the output variable.

Comment: Adding your code helps @SocketM!